# PHP Smarty condition - if Y or if Y condition

Tags: php, smarty

I have two variables that either pass back N or Y but only want to show something either either one of those is set to Y but think I'm doing it wrong. Any ideas?

```
{if $product.bean_bag_filling_150 == "Y" || $product.bean_bag_filling_300 == "Y"}
```

I'm assuming that would show the contents inside that condition if at least one of those has a value of "Y"?

Comment: Parenthesis? `if ($product.bean_bag_filling_150 == "Y" || $product.bean_bag_filling_300 == "Y")`

Comment: I just tried that, but only shows if both are set to "Y" if one if set to "y" and the other "n" wont show... i need to show if either one of those are set to "y"

Comment: `"Y"  != "y"`. Posted an answer that might help you.

Comment: "Y" != "y" is not in your Answer... what one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{if (strtolower($product.bean_bag_filling_150) == "y" || strtolower($product.bean_bag_filling_300) == "y")}
```

Read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: surely you can add a condition so show if either a = Y or b = Y, so if a = N and b = Y would show or even if both = Y would show....

Comment: Opps sorry seemed it did work, was looking at the wrong product :) think could help me on this one as well? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32019976/4520308 thanks again mate

Comment: Great! I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo! really appreciate your help and time mate..... ill keep refreshing the other question haha